# Javascript Bitbucket API Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsfiddle

I'm firing off an API request to Bitbucket via AJAX, but I'm getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in Chrome.

I've had a look at similar posts on here with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, but none of the solutions there work for me.

My script loads public repos from Github and Bitbucket. Github works great, but Bitucket doesn't.

I think the error is around line 158:

```
// Fire off the json request
jsonRequest.open("GET", endPoint, true);
jsonRequest.send();
```

I've made a jsfiddle for easy diagnosis: http://jsfiddle.net/Todd_Davies/8buAD/